# simple option script for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to made a options site for my Chrome Extension. I want just that if checkbox 1 is enable script is runs etc...
I searched around but I found only outdated threads for this topic.
This is the `manifest.json` from my extension:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.example.com/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["script1.js", "script2.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*.example.com/*"
  ]
}
```

The `options.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="uber-frame" i18n-values=".style.fontFamily:fontfamily;.style.fontSize:fontsize" style="font-family: &#39;Segoe UI&#39;, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 125%">
<div id="main-content" align="center">
  <div id="mainview">
    <section id="scripts">
<h3>Scripts</h3>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class=script1 >
        <span>Enable Script 1</span>
     </label>
    <div>
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class=script2>
        <span>Enable Script 2</span>
     </label>
    </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I don' t know how can i say the extension wich script shout be activ and which not.
I think I need a other script to get the values from the classes of the checkboxes and 
probably I should set the content scripts to backgrond scripts. 
Would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

**I've updated all codes for make both script run at the same time.**

OK, at first you should save options data in localstorage, so you can access data from all pages. that makes your job easy.

For manipulating data I've created a javascript file named as `global.js`.

This file must be included at the start of `options.html` and `content.js` manually or in `manifest.json`.

### global.js

```
var localStoragePrefix = "myextension_";
var LS_options  = localStoragePrefix + "options";
var Options = {
    Scripts : [
        {
            name : "script 1",
            path : "script1.js",
            enable : false
        },
        {
            name : "script 2",
            path : "script2.js",
            enable : false
        }
    ]
};

function DB_setValue(name, value, callback) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = value;
    console.log("ayarlar kaydedildi");
    console.log(obj);
    chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function() {
        if(callback) callback();
    });
}

function DB_load(callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(LS_options, function(r) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(r[LS_options])) {
            DB_setValue(LS_options, Options, callback);
        } else {
            Options = r[LS_options];
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function DB_save(callback) {
    DB_setValue(LS_options, Options, function() {
        if(callback) callback();
    });
}

function DB_clear(callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.remove(LS_options, function() {
        if(callback) callback();
    });
}
```

And here is the updated options.html, you will see some js files included.

- jquery.min.js (You don't need to use this, I just want to make it more useful)
- global.js
- options.js

### options.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="globals.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="uber-frame" i18n-values=".style.fontFamily:fontfamily;.style.fontSize:fontsize" style="font-family: &#39;Segoe UI&#39;, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 125%">
<div id="main-content" align="center">
  <div id="mainview">
    <section id="scripts">
      <h3>Scripts</h3>
      <div id="scriptTemplate" style="display:none">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-script = "script.js" />
          <span>Enable Script</span>
       </label>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Event handler attachments are in `options.js` file.

### options.js

$(function(){
    DB_load(startOptionsPage);
});

```
function startOptionsPage() {

    $.each(Options.Scripts, function(index, script) {
       var $scriptTemplate = $("#scriptTemplate").clone().show();
       $scriptTemplate.find("label span").html("Enable " + script.name);

       $scriptTemplate.find("label input[type='checkbox']")
       .data("script", script.path)
       .click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              script.enable = true; 
          } else {
              script.enable = false;
          }
          DB_save(function() {
              console.log("DB saved");
          });
       })
       .prop('checked', script.enable);

       $("#scripts").append($scriptTemplate);
    });    
}
```

And in `content.js` file we are getting Options and including the script if there is a selected one.

### content.js

```
DB_load(function() {    
    $.each(Options.Scripts, function(index, script) {
        if (script.enable) {
            $.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL(script.path), function() {
                console.log(script.name + " was loaded!");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### script1.js

```
alert("Hello from script1");
```

### script2.js

```
alert("Hello from script2");
```

For all of this you should update the `manifest.json` file.

- including `global.js` into the `content_script`
- permission for `localstorage`
- including web_accessible_resources for script1.js and script2.js ([Why?](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources))

Finally here is the updated `manifest.json`

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","globals.js","content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://stackoverflow.com/*", "storage"
  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
    "script1.js",
    "script2.js"
  ]
}
```

Your script folder should be like this,

[image]

### How can I add more scripts?

There are only two changes you must make,

You will add script to main folder like the other script1.js and script2.js, and also you will add it to  `web_accessible_resources` into the `manifest.json`.

You will also update "global.js", just add new script object to Options.Scripts array. like this.

```
var Options = {
    Scripts : [
        {
            name : "script 1",
            path : "script1.js",
            enable : false
        },
        {
            name : "script 2",
            path : "script2.js",
            enable : false
        },
        {
            name : "script 3",
            path : "script3.js",
            enable : false
        }
    ]
};
```

**That's all. But don't forget to remove extension from chrome before you load the new updated one, because old options will stay  there, and that won't work as you expect if don't do that.**

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I enable both scripts no one works.

Comment: @Michael I have updated, now both of them can be enabled at the same time.

Comment: I tried to add a third script & option, but I failed miserably. What should I do to add more options?

Comment: This code is not useful if you will change script numbers dynamically.  if you want to add more script file, you must change almost all pages.  I recommend that you can improve this code to make it more useful(like making an array for script files). If you really don't know how you can do that, tell me, I can update my answer again. I don't have much time right now.

Comment: I've tried to copy all arrays from script2 and rename it to script3, but then the scripts of extension not working and it just reloads the target sites... If you have more time it would be nice to show me how I can add more options.

Comment: I've updated it again, and you will see an instruction in my answer below that tells you how to add a new script file.

Comment: Thank you, I've exactly done what you wrote, but it doesn't work. (I've also tried to add a script3 array to the content.js, option.js and option.html but no way works).

Comment: @Michael I think the problem is you are not removing the old one, so localstorage are not resetting therefore it's working with old options. Or maybe you must make a mistake while copying. [Here is my extension files](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39457223/ocanal/ScriptLoader.zip), try this one, it's working like a charm for me.